Should a roof gutter collect water from the valley?
Wondering if I'm out of line asking the company to come back and fix these ends. There are two like this and don't collect water from the roof creases, and one side then results in the water running down my stucco. The company said they would have to tear them off and redo them if I wanted this fixed.


That is just an odd roof configuration. It will take a custom fabricated metal trough to do anything there and that still will produce minimal results.

Asking our opinion on how you interact with your contractor makes the question off topic here. Please see the [help] and take the [tour]. Better would be to ask how this might be resolved, then you can make your own decision on how to proceed.

What's at the bottom of the narrow section of roof - the part underneath the gutter?

All of my valleys end at, and empty into, gutters at the bottom of the runs.

It should be quite easy to fashion a piece of "tin"(thin steel)  to funnel water from the valley to the gutter.  Quite sure I have seen a kitchen tool/dust pan of the right shape, a large ladle with a wide sprout to pour.

This is a bad job. closing the end of a gutter at an angle other than vertical is a tricky job. so feeding the valley gutter into the edge gutter is not a simple task.
